# PHP MYSQL_RESULT Array issue

Tags: php, mysql

**I have a variable called**

```
$staff=mysql_query($aSQL, $staffDirectory) or die(mysql_error());
```

**And the display of list is here:**

```
<table>
<?php if(!empty($row_staff)){  do { ?>
 <tr>
<td rowspan="3"><?php 
if( !isset($row_staff['photo'])){
        echo "<img width='100px' src='images/user_default.PNG'/>";
    }else{
        echo "<img width='100px' src='".$row_staff['photo']."'/>"; 
    }
?></td>
<td align="left"><h4 ><span class="staffList"><?php echo $row_staff['name_eng']; ?><br />
</span></h4>
 <h4> <span class="staffList"><?php echo $row_staff['name_chi']; ?>    </span></h4></td>
<td rowspan="3"><span class="staffList"><img src="images/phone32.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" />  <?php echo $row_staff['contact_no']; ?><br />
    <img src="images/printer32.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" />  <?php echo $row_staff['fax_no']; ?><br />
    <img src="images/mail32.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" />  <?php echo $row_staff['email']; ?></span></td>
</tr>
  <tr>      
    <td>
  <p><span class="staffList"><?php echo $row_staff['groupname']; ?><br />
    <?php echo $row_staff['department']; ?><br />
    Joined on : 
    <?php echo $row_staff['date_join']; ?></span></p></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td valign="middle"><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_staff = mysql_fetch_assoc($staff));} ?>
```

And I used this staff various to display a list, so the list by default will just display everything. And when I perform some sorting or searching, I will change this staff variable and my list will get updated.

My problem now is that I wanted to export the array to a XLS file, everything is fine except for the array.

**here is the code**

```
    $i=0;
        for($x = 0;$x<mysql_num_rows($staff);$x++){
        //do{
            $i = $x+2;
            mysql_data_seek($staff,$x);
            $array = mysql_fetch_row($staff);
```

This $staff variable remains the same as the initial one, so no matter how I perform my search and sorting, the display list will show the result, but when I try to retrieve this variable, it remains as the initial one which displays everything. So, I am really confused, how shall I solve it ? I am really confused ...

Comment: Is $array an array variable or ordinary variable?

Comment: $array is an array variable that is accessed using index

Answer (score 0):

you are using  `$row_staff` before the while loop of fetching your sql.

you will not get any data and it will be undefined variable `$row_staff`

Comment: row_staff is to store a record of the mysql_result that the pointer currently points, so it changes every time I retrieve the mysql_result variable, it serves the same purpose as $array variable

Comment: $row_staff is defined in the last of your code. when u use while loop. but you are using it before it defined.

Comment: That is a snippet of codes ... it was defined when the page is loaded ... that part of code doesn't have problem, problem is that the list come out from $staff is correct, but when I retrieve the instance from the same $staff, it's not ...